# If two sequences converge, then the sequence of distances between them also converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, metric-spaces

Question:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, and let $(a_{n})$ , $(b_{n})$ be convergent sequences in X with limit a, b respectively. Prove that $$(d(a_{n}),(b_{n}))$$ is a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ with limit $d(a,b)$. Hint: $$d(a_{n},b_{n}) \leq  d(a_{n},a) + d(a,b) + d(b,b_{n}).$$

My attempt:

Since $(a_{n})$ convergent, there exist $N_{1}$ such that for all $n \gt N_{1}$,  $d(a_{n},a) \lt \epsilon/2$. Similarly, since $(b_{n})$ convergent, there exist $N_{2}$ such that for all $n \gt N_{2}$, $d(b_{n},b) \lt \epsilon/2$.

Using the hint:

$d(a_{n},b_{n}) \leq  d(a_{n},a) + d(a,b) + d(b,b_{n})$ .....  (1)

Also, $d(a,b) \leq  d(a_{n},a) + d(a_{n},b_{n}) + d(b,b_{n})$ .....  (2)

I know to pick $N = max(N_{1},N_{2})$ so that we are guaranteed convergence for any $n$ larger than this.

I am stuck at the first inequality of the supplied solution:
$$|d(a_{n},b_{n}) - d(a,b)| \leq  d(a_{n},a) + d(b,b_{n}) \lt \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon. $$

I tried taking the absolute difference between (1) and (2) above but can't seem to arrive at the given expression. Can someone please show me how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n\geqslant N$, we have from $(1)$ that
$$d(a_n, b_n)-d(a,b) \leqslant d(a_n,a) + d(b_n,b) <\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2 = \varepsilon, $$
and from $(2)$ that
$$d(a,b)-d(a_n,b_n) \leqslant d(a_n,a) + d(b_n,b) <\frac\varepsilon2+\frac\varepsilon2 = \varepsilon.$$
Combining these yields the desired
$$|d(a_n,b_n)-d(a,b)|\leqslant d(a_n,a)+d(b_n,b)<\varepsilon.$$

Comment: Thank you Math1000! From your working, I am assuming the reason why you showed why flipping the expression on the left hand side is equivalent, is to mean that we can simply write it between the absolute bars, which is as per required in the definition of convergence

Comment: Yes, it follows from $|a|\leqslant b$ if and only if $a\leqslant b$ and $-a\leqslant b$.

Comment: Can you please explain why the given hint is true?